# F#, System.IO.IOException: All pipe instances are busy

Tags: java, f#, io

I have a F# application that communicates with a java application via named pipe. Where F# acts as server and java acts as client. The application works for the most part except that the F# runes in to “System.IO.IOException: All pipe instances are busy” error occasionally. Below is the full stack trace of the exception and code snip of both F# and Java. Any help is appreciated in resolving this issue

Thanks,
Sudaly

**full stack trace:**

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.IOException: All pipe instances are busy.
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.CancellationTokenOps.Start@1143-1.Invoke(Exception e)
   at <StartupCode$FSharp-Core>.$Control.loop@413-38(Trampoline this, FSharpFunc`2 action)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.Trampoline.ExecuteAction(FSharpFunc`2 firstAction)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.TrampolineHolder.Protect(FSharpFunc`2 firstAction)
   at <StartupCode$FSharp-Core>.$Control.-ctor@473-1.Invoke(Object state)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

**F# Code:**

```
[<DataContract>] 
type Quote = { 
    [<field: DataMember(Name="securityIdentifier") >] 
    RicCode:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name="madeOn") >] 
    MadeOn:DateTime
    [<field: DataMember(Name="closePrice") >] 
    Price:int 
    }

let globalPriceCache = new Dictionary<string, Quote>()

let ParseQuoteString (quoteString:string) = 
    let data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(quoteString)
    let stream = new MemoryStream() 
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length); 
    stream.Position <- 0L 
    let ser = Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof<Quote array>) 
    let results:Quote array = ser.ReadObject(stream) :?> Quote array
    results

let RefreshCache quoteList =
    globalPriceCache.Clear() 
    quoteList 
    |> Array.iter(fun result->globalPriceCache.Add(result.RicCode, result)) 

let EstablishConnection() =
    let pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream("testpipe", PipeDirection.InOut, 4)
    pipeServer.WaitForConnection()
    try
        Some(new StreamReader(pipeServer))
    with e -> 
        None

let rec MarketPriceCache() =
    match EstablishConnection() with
    |Some(sr) ->
        // Read request from the stream.
        let m_cache = 
            sr.ReadLine()  
            |>  ParseQuoteString  
            |>  RefreshCache

        MarketPriceCache()
    | _ -> () 


[<EntryPoint>]
let main args=
    try
        async { 
            MarketPriceCache() 
        } |> Async.Start

        while true do
            if globalPriceCache.Count > 0 then
    //Business logic
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000 * 50)
            else

                ignore(logInfo(sprintf "%s" "Price Cache is empty"))
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000 * 65)

    with e ->
        ignore(logError e.Message)
        ignore(logError e.StackTrace)    
    0
```

**Java Code:**

```
public void WatchForPrice()
 {
  while (true)
  {
   try 
   {
    Map<String, SecurityQuoteCacheEntry> priceMap = getPriceCache().getCacheMap();
    List<LocalSecurityQuote> localSecurityQuotes = new ArrayList<LocalSecurityQuote>();
    if(priceMap != null)
    {

     Set<String> keySet = priceMap.keySet();
     System.out.println("Key Size: " + keySet.size());
     for(String key : keySet)
     {
      SecurityQuote quote =  priceMap.get(key).getQuote();
      if(quote != null)
      {
       LocalSecurityQuote localSecurityQuote = new LocalSecurityQuote();
       localSecurityQuote.setClosePrice(quote.getClosePrice());
       localSecurityQuote.setMadeOn(quote.getMadeOn());     
       localSecurityQuote.setSecurityIdentifier(key);
       localSecurityQuotes.add(localSecurityQuote);
      }

     }

     JSONSerializer serializer = new JSONSerializer();
     String jsonString = serializer.serialize(localSecurityQuotes);

     // Connect to the pipe
     RandomAccessFile pipe = new RandomAccessFile("\\\\.\\pipe\\testpipe", "rw");
     if (pipe != null )
     {
      // write to pipe
      pipe.write(jsonString.getBytes());
      pipe.close();

     }
     else
      System.out.println("Pipe not found");
     doPeriodicWait();
    }
    else 
     System.out.println("No Price data found");
   }
   catch (Exception e) 
   {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    doPeriodicWait();
   }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a hunch, but maybe the issue is that you are not closing your pipe stream reader?

```
let rec MarketPriceCache() =
match EstablishConnection() with
|Some(sr) ->
    // Read request from the stream.        
    try        
        sr.ReadLine()  
        |>  ParseQuoteString  
        |>  RefreshCache   
    finally
        sr.Close()
    MarketPriceCache()
| _ -> ()
```

(m_cache variable is not needed - you are not using it anywhere)

Comment: Thank you Mitya, i'll give your solution a try and let you know the result

Answer (score 3):

You have to dispose of the `NamedPipeServerStream` every time you create one. The easiest way to do this in your code is to dispose of the `StreamReader` inside `MarketPriceCache` by putting a `use` statement around it:

```
let rec MarketPriceCache() =
    match EstablishConnection() with
    | Some(sr) ->
        // Read request from the stream.
        use reader = sr in
        (
            let m_cache = 
                reader.ReadLine()  
                |>  ParseQuoteString  
                |>  RefreshCache
        )
        MarketPriceCache()
    | _ -> ()
```

The syntax with `using ... in` is there to prevent that the scope of the reader ends after the recursive call to `MarketPriceCache`.

Comment: Thank you Ronald, i'll give your solution a try and let you know the result

Comment: Actually, both my solution and the one by Mitya are correct. The `use` binding is translated by the compiler to a try/finally statement that calls `Dispose` in the finally branch. A `use` binding is considered a more high-level construct.